# What was the function of the Amudim in the Mishkan?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, vayakhel

Kerashim were the pillars that comprised the walls. So what were the Amudim?

Answer (score 1):

There were four components of the *mishkan* that were hung on *amudim*:

1. The *[parochet](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.36.36?lang=bi)* (curtain dividing between the *kodesh* and *kodesh hakodoshim*)
2. The *[masach hapetach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.36.38?lang=bi)* (screen at the entrance to the *kodesh*)
3. The *[kal'ei hechatzer](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.38.10?lang=bi)* (curtains that formed the boundary of the courtyard of the *mishkan*)
4. The *[masach sha'ar hechatzer](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.38.19?lang=bi)* (screen at the entrance to the courtyard).

As you note, these *amudim* are distinct from the *[kerashim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.36.20?lang=bi)* which formed the walls of the main *mishkan* structure (*kodesh* and *kodesh hakodoshim*).

Comment: Right. The *kerashim* formed a solid-wood wall for the main structure; the *amudei hechatzer* supported the fabric wall surrounding the courtyard around it.

Comment: Were the Amudim any different than the Kerashim, besides how they were called?

Comment: @larry909 among other things, the Kerashim were bound together by long, horizontal poles -- including one that went right through them, so they had a hole drilled in the middle; the Amudim were not connected by horizontal poles (as an Amud wasn't touching another Amud); the Amud had hooks on its top for hanging tapestries (to fill in the wide gaps between them, while the Kerashim formed a wall and had a tapestry ceiling sitting on top. (So they didn't need hardware on top.) The Kerashim were gold-plated, while the Amudim were silver-plated.